# In these two query result of TDengine, why is the number after the decimal point different?

Tags: tdengine

As you see:

First SQL's result is 457445.014572144

second one is 457445.000000000：

```
taos>  select time, price, vol, price*vol*100  as amount from sh600096 where time > '2022-12-15' limit 1;
```

> ```
>       time              |        price         |     vol     |          amount
> ========================================================================================           
> 2022-12-15 09:30:24.000 |             23.95000 |         191 |          457445.014572144 
>
> Query OK, 10 row(s) in set (0.071000s)
> ```

```
taos> select 23.95*191*100  as amount;
```

> ```
>           amount           |
> ============================
>           457445.000000000 |
> Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.008000s)
> ```

Below is my create table statement :

```
CREATE STABLE `st_transaction_data` (
    `time` TIMESTAMP, 
    `price` FLOAT, 
    `vol` INT, 
    `buyorsell` TINYINT
    ) 
TAGS (
    `market` TINYINT
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a FLOAT is used, however in most languages FLOAT is an inaccuratie datatype. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) question and answers for more explaination.

When you change your FLOAT to a DECIMAL, it should give precise results.